# Overflow text box adds white space on bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I'm not really sure how to explain this, as I'm still new to coding, but I am attempting to make a profile layout for HEX, and I keep having this issue come up on every one I make:

[image]

I noticed that when I edit my scrollbox, the white space changes its size accordingly. The bigger the scroll box, the bigger the space and vice versa. Here's the code to my last profile:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/X3qmTN2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e80812;
  text-alignment: justify;
}
#nav {
  width: 400px;  
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 670px;
}


#nav a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav a:active {
  display: block;
  font: 14px  "arial";
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
  color: #ab4860; 

  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

#nav a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #74194e;
  padding: 7px 2px;
}
  .hex {
    position: relative;
    top: 600px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .owl {
    position: relative;
    top: 800px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .club {
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  b { color: #ab4860; }
  u { color: #ab4860; }
  i  { color: #ab4860; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="hex"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/my.php">Back to HEX</a></div><br>
<div class="owl"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/owlpost.php?action=compose">Owl Me</a></div><br>
<div class="club"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/f/16063">Club Rainbow Brigade</a></div><br>
</div>

<div align="left">
<div style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:700px;height:720px;top:-350px;left:390px;margin-right:-546px;margin-bottom:-300px;">
Text here. <b>Bold.</b> <u>Underlined.</u> <i>Italic.</i></div>

</body>
```

Is there something I need to add, or remove in my code? Did I mess up somewhere and I can't see it?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My question is right there: Do I need to add something, remove something? Or did I do something wrong that messed it up?

Comment: I edited the snippet because there was a disaster and it doesnt work.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I need an explanation. And trying whatever it is you changed made the problem worse.

Comment: I don't change anything on your code, only make a correct snippet with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BR tags were your downfall, I've changed a few other things too.

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="hex"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/my.php">Back to HEX</a></div>
  <div class="owl"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/owlpost.php?action=compose">Owl Me</a></div>
  <div class="club"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/f/16063">Club Rainbow Brigade</a></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/xxvkzz28/

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I edit your code and get a working solution:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/X3qmTN2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color:#e80812;
  font-family:arial, sans-serif;
  height:1660px;
  text-align: justify;
  width:1300px;
}
#nav {
  line-height:80px;
  position:absolute;
  top:640px;
  width:400px;  
}
#nav a:link, 
#nav a:visited, 
#nav a:active {
  color: #ab4860; 
  display: block;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:2px; 
  padding:7px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none; 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  transition:all .5s ease-out;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color:#74194e;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  padding:7px 2px;
}
.hex {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.owl {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top:15px;
}
.club {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top:30px;
}
.content {
  height:850px;
  left:390px;
  overflow:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:640px;
  width:910px;
}
b, u, i {
  color: #ab4860;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div class="hex"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/my.php">Back to HEX</a></div>
  <div class="owl"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/owlpost.php?action=compose">Owl Me</a></div>
  <div class="club"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/f/16063">Club Rainbow Brigade</a></div>
</div>
<div align="left">
  <div class="content">Text here. <b>Bold.</b> <u>Underlined.</u> <i>Italic.</i></div>
</div>
```

There was some typos in your HTML and CSS code. I solved this and do some changes to place all the elements to the right place.

A working fiddle you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/hhf2kpLd/

Comment: The background isn't supposed to get cut off like that.

Comment: @sebastianbrosh The background is supposed to be complete, the way you did it, part of it gets cut off.

Comment: added some optimization

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, by this mode the menu's texts are positioned in his place. Top and left are 0 pixels. See the snippet in fullpage:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/X3qmTN2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e80812;
  /* text-alignment doesnt exists, it's text align*/
  text-align: justify;
}
#nav {
  width: 400px;  
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 670px;
}


#nav a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav a:active {
  display: block;
  font: 14px  "arial";
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
  color: #ab4860; 

  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

#nav a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #74194e;
  padding: 7px 2px;
}
  .hex {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .owl {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .club {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
  b { color: #ab4860; }
  u { color: #ab4860; }
  i  { color: #ab4860; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="hex"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/my.php">Back to HEX</a></div><br>
<div class="owl"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/owlpost.php?action=compose">Owl Me</a></div><br>
<div class="club"><a href="http://www.hexrpg.com/f/16063">Club Rainbow Brigade</a></div><br>
</div>

<div align="left">
<div style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:700px;height:720px;top:-350px;left:390px;margin-right:-546px;margin-bottom:-300px;">
Text here. <b>Bold.</b> <u>Underlined.</u> <i>Italic.</i></div>
```

Comment: The problem remains, though. There's still a white space at the bottom and it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

The div

```
<div style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:700px;height:720px;top:-350px;left:390px;margin-right:-546px;margin-bottom:-300px;">
    Text here. <b>Bold.</b> <u>Underlined.</u> <i>Italic.</i></div>
```

Makes your content to be out of the delimited area of your html content. Use your Browser Inspector to see it. I think that some browsers will interpret your code in a different way and the result will be different (with some blank space for example).
Can you first upload your img on another site (like casimage.com) cause it's lock on my side (proxy limitation) ? And then you should structure your site on a different way, with no relative or absolute position.